# Query on Edge triggered D-flipflop using SR-latches

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, latch, sequential-logic

[image: Edge Triggered D-Flipflop]

When clk is 0 and during this time let us assume d is 0 this drives r and rbar to be 1. Isn't this a forbidden case of SR latch?? After this state if clk and d becomes 1 at the same time wont it cause a indeterminate state at r??

Comment: that logic diagram has no terms named `D`, `R`  `Clk`  and `CLK`

Comment: NAND gates do not have indeterminate states. You can always work out the output state from the input values.

Comment: @CL. NAND gates do not have indeterminate states but a **latch** can, and that is what the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

clk is inverted so what you're concerned about is clk changing from 1 to 0 while d is 0. That does make both r and rbar 1 to begin with. It's the way it's supposed to work. Then when clk becomes 0 and d becomes 1 at the same time r and rbar will be indeterminate, brief oscillations are possible before one of them ends up as 1 and the other 0. This is a well known phenomenon called metastability. So all the practical implementations of this type of flip-flop specify setup and hold times, which are the times before and after clk changes to the state that strobes in the value of d when d must not change state. See the data sheet for the SN7474. It's just like your diagram, except it also has a set input as well as a clear and doesn't invert clk.